# Need help in accessing dictionary values in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to access the values in list of dictionary where I need to pass `key` and `value` as string

ex: I have list of dictionary -

```
details = [{'name': 'veeresh', 'href': 'www.google.com', 'id': '12345'}, {'name': 'Chandan', 'href': 'www.facebook.com', 'id': '67895'}]
```

I want to access `href` attribute based on name I pass

If I try below -

`details['name']['href']`

I am getting an error -

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Is there any other way to access it?

Comment: What happens if more than one dictionary has the same (duplicated) name?

Comment: No, it will be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop to check for the `name` you passed and return the respective `href` attribute -

```
def get_href(details, name):
    for values in details:
        if values['name'] == name:
            return values['href']

href_val = get_href(details, 'veeresh')
```

Answer (score 1):

A list's items can only be accessed sequentially or by index (positions).  you would either have to perform a sequential search or build a dictionary of dictionaries with the name as its key.

For example:

```
details = [{'name': 'veeresh', 'href': 'www.google.com', 'id': '12345'},
           {'name': 'Chandan', 'href': 'www.facebook.com', 'id': '67895'}]

nameDetails = { d['name']:d for d in details }

nameDetails['veeresh']['href'] # 'www.google.com'
```